# Is it possible to fix my USB that can't even be read by Disk Management

Tags: windows, usb, disk, usb-drive, disk-io

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, but every time I find a thread about corrupted USB, disk management is still at least able to recognize a drive. My USB is so bricked that when I try to use disk management, nothing loads. When I unplug it the other disks load fine, but once I plug it in and refresh the program hangs. Same things happens when I run diskpart and when I use any other third party disk managing software. Is this USB just completely FUBAR or can I raise it from the dead? Device manager recognizes a USB is plugged in, but that's about as much as Windows can do. I'm running Win10 64-bit version 1809 build 17763.1217. If there is any other info I can provide please let me know. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to recover critical data from it? If not, then just throw it out and move on with your life.

Comment: There is no critical data luckily, but this is a 128GB USB and I really don't want to spend another $20 to buy another. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Even if you do get it working again, since you know for sure it's flaky, there's a much higher chance it will quickly die permanently, and maybe the next time it will have critical data on it.

Comment: Weeelllll it's not flaky. The bricking was my fault. I was trying to reformat the drive but I thought the reformatting software was glitching so I tried to exit. My computer began to hang so I pulled out the drive. I'm pretty sure that's what corrupted it. Before you say it, I know, that was really really dumb. Can I fix it though?

Comment: Can Linux see it any better?

Comment: I just left work, but I’ll load up a distro on my vm when I get home.